# In angular-ui-router can I check for state and a parameter at the same time?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to do something like the following command.

```
 state.is('home.auth({content: 'login'})')
```

It always shows as valid even when I send a different content parameter. Is there a way I can also check for the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
state.is('home.auth', {content: 'login'});
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateisstateorname--params).